# Why Ash does not grow up?

Tags: pokemon

In all the series only the dress is changed.
Ash doesn't grow up or does his maturity changes.
What is the reason?

Comment: Probably because it would drastically change the demographic of the show. In *Digimon*, they introduced new kids and aged out the old ones, whereas *Pokemon* thought keeping the original character was probably a better idea.